# Save the Count result of a query into a variable to use for arithmetic in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, variables

I ran a query to get the count of the number of participants that completed an assignment.  I want to take that number and save it into a variable so I can then use it to calculate an average.

The query that returns a number is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [2019 Learning]
WHERE [Course Name] = "5 C's of Communication" AND [Assignment Status] = 'Completed') AS [# Complete]
```

I want to find a way to save this number in a variable and then use that variable for further calculation.

I am using Microsoft Access 2016.  Assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `avg` function directly, for example:

```
select avg(iif([Assignment Status] = 'Completed'), 1, 0)
from [2019 Learning]
where [Course Name] = "5 C's of Communication"
```

Comment: I figured out how to make it work with switch statement.     SELECT [Course Name], COUNT(Switch([Assignment Status] IN ('Completed','Withdrawn'), 1)) AS Total, COUNT(Switch([Assignment Status] = 'Completed', 1)) AS Completed, COUNT(Switch([Assignment Status] = 'Withdrawn', 1)) AS Dropped
FROM [2019 Learning]
GROUP BY [Course Name];

Comment: I'm curious as to why you opted for `switch` over `iif` when faced with a binary decision? e.g. `select sum(iif([assignment status] in ('Completed', 'Withdrawn'),1,0), ...`